# How to keep a specific symbol in binary file?

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu, ld, autotools

I have a static lib (`my_static_lib`) which I link to an executable binary file. Some of the symbols, but not all, are used in my binary.

A second library, dynamically loaded(`my_shared_lib`), is expecting to receive some symbols from my_static_lib through symbol injection from the binary. But those symbols are not used by my_binary, so they are stripped off the final bin file.

So, at runtime, `my_shared_lib` complains that it cannot find `__my_stripped_symbols__` and crashes.

Is there a way to force the linker to keep `__my_stripped_symbols__`? I would prefer something that can be cleanly written in a Makefile.am (autotools)

```
(-binary file makefile)
-L$(top_builddir)/static_lib -lmy_static_lib --magic-flag-to-keep-stripped-symbol
```

I do not want to link `my_static_lib` with `my_shared_lib` because it will generate strange conflicts in other parts of a rather complex group of executables/shared libraries.

Answer (score 4):

When you link `my_static_lib` to your application, you want to use the `--whole-archive` option.  It's documented in the [ld options docs](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html#Options).

If you're linking with gcc, it looks something like this:

```
-L$(top_builddir)/static_lib -Wl,-whole-archive -lmy_static_lib -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

That will make sure the entire library is kept, and not just the specific functions that your executable uses.

You also need to make sure that the symbols get exported.  If the symbols from your static library aren't being exported already, you make need a combination of `-fvisibility=hidden` and use `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` to mark up the ones you want exported.  You can read a little more about it in the [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fvisibility-2281)